# How important is the PhD school reputation in securing a faculty position?

Tags: phd, faculty-application, tenure-track

New assistant professors and selection committee members, based on your experience how important is the reputation of the PhD school in selecting a candidate for a tenure track faculty position? Can you please share your experience in supporting your argument? Thanks!

Edit 1: My PhD school was Penn State and my degree was in Electrical Engineering

Comment: @Anyon I guess I look for actual examples as opposed to opinions. I probably should add that my PhD school was Penn State and my degree was in Electrical Engineering.

Comment: Actually, the first answer does provide examples.

Comment: @Dilworth About CS mostly

Comment: close enough obviously

Comment: @Dilworth I believe it’s very dangerous to assume hiring faculty in CS and EE are “obviously” similar as each of them are simply labels for a myriad of research areas. Thus I rather settle for the most diverse examples and hope to try to find a pattern among examples in different majors. Nonetheless, thanks for your input

Comment: Thanks. I definitely disagree. EE and CS are almost identical for this specific question, and for this specific website. How would it be different?

Comment: @Dilworth I wouldn’t know if it’s different. However, I’m simply betting on the fact that if an output (or trend) in hiring faculty (with respect to my question) holds for various majors, then it probably will hold for mine as well. Otherwise, I don’t see how uniquely similar CS is to EE as opposed to any other major (with regards to hiring faculty)

Comment: The question has many answers from different areas.